# Change File Directory of microlog4android?

Tags: android, logging

I'm using **microlog4android** to log my details into a File.

Do any one know how to change the Textfile path of the microlog.txt created in the SD Card while using microlog4android.

or suggest me with anyother good logging method.

Comment: You can use the Log4j

check here for details[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21307968/log4j-in-android][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21307968/log4j-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the microlog you can simply use the log4j

the complete tutorial is [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Log4j to add logs to your project

check here for details [LOG4J in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21307968/log4j-in-android)