# Storing logcat of particular app into device storage as txt file

Tags: android, android-logcat

I tried this

```
 try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        log=new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            log.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    //convert log to string
    final String logString = new String(log.toString());
```

but this copies the logcat for whole device. I only want logcat for particular application in which this method is called.

I tried several adb commands like this

```
adb logcat | grep `adb shell ps | grep com.example.package | cut -c10-15`
```

but this command makes no file and app doesnt star/launch.

Please help.

Comment: why don't you use `log4j` logger instead?

Comment: I am new to android ... i tried log4j but it only logs cutomized statement that we enter in code... what I want is proper logcat as shown in the ADB debugger. Can we do that using log4j??

Comment: you can use `de.mindpipe.android:android-logging-log4j` to be able to log into `logcat` and into a file. check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21307968/log4j-in-android