# Log4j configure for Android using gradle

Tags: android, gradle, log4j

I want to use log4j to write logs to sdcard. How to configure log4j specifically using gradle ?

Many threads I have seen ask to download and add jar as library, I can't find a good post on configuring log4j using gradle.

Comment: did you download the log4j library??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21307968/log4j-in-android) describes the solution using using the [android-logging-log4j.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.mindpipe.android/android-logging-log4j).

Gradle dependencies for the same:

> Original code

```
compile group: 'de.mindpipe.android', name: 'android-logging-log4j', version: '1.0.3'
compile group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.17'
```

> Updated : Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.

```
implementation 'de.mindpipe.android:android-logging-log4j:1.0.3'
implementation 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
```

Comment: `android-logging-log4j` already has  the dependency to `log4j` https://github.com/eetac/android-logging-log4j/blob/master/pom.xml#L117