# Usin maven jar with log4j 2.7 in Android API 22 Java 8 gets java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, log4j

I have a Maven project that use Log4j for logging.
This i my pom.xml

```
<!-- Log4J Bridge -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Log4J 2 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>
            
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
<dependency>
```

In the classes where i use logger i do:

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);
```

then in the methods

```
LOGGER.debug("Logger works");
```

It works perfectly.
Now, if i build a jar from this project, install it in local maven repo and import it in the Android project (API 22), i have this error at runtime

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ReflectionUtil$PrivateSecurityManager.getCallerClass(ReflectionUtil.java:317)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ReflectionUtil.getCallerClass(ReflectionUtil.java:225)
at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:42)
at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:363)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:388)

I read more post in stackoverflow but i don't have a solutions yet.
I added this in manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Debugging code, i see that in the class java.lang.SecurityManager the method getSecurityContext always return null.

```
public Object getSecurityContext() {
    return null;
}
```

Any help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21307968/log4j-in-android

Comment: Note that it is poor practice to include implementations such as `log4j-core` as dependencies in libraries; libraries should depend only on the API packages and allow the client programs to select the implementation.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- i seen this post but i would not want to change the code of the external jar library since it works outside android

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- if i remove log4j-core i have this error ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...

Comment: You get that _in the final application_, which is where you should put the `-core` dependency.